# Google Analytics - Export data in real time (> 30 seconds) to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, real-time

I would like to analyze users that are currently on my website and assign them to a category (within 1 minute)
What I need is a kind of solution to export data from Google Analytics to a MySQL database within 30 seconds or less.

I have talked to Solution Engineers from HEVO and they told me that it isn't possible to send data from Google Analytics to a MySQL Database within 30 seconds or less.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because Google Analytics has a processing latency (4 hours for  GA360, and up to 24 hours for the free version) to assemble the reports. Only then the data is accessible via the API. (This is for Universal Analytics, the new version of GA promises to cut down on the processing latency).

If you have GA360 you can set up a BigQuery export and select the "streaming" option - this comes at a (moderate) fee, with streaming exports being slightly more expensive than daily exports. You can then run SQL queries in BigQuery, or export the data to any other database.

With the free version you are out of luck.

Comment: But the latency of GA360 with that BigQuery export will still be 4 hours?
So there is no way to analyze users who are currently on a website?

Comment: No, you will receive hit level data in near-realtime (not quite 30 seconds, though). Processing latency is the time until the GA reports are calculated. In BQ, you have to do your own aggregations. Some session-level fields will not be available. Details here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726?hl=en